# How does the Observer notify_observers() pass *args to observer

Tags: ruby, observer-pattern, observable

Here is the code:

```
class Notifier
  def update(car, miles)
    puts "The car has logged #{miles} miles, totaling #{car.mileage} miles traveled."
    puts "The car needs to be taken in for a service!" if car.service <= car.mileage
  end
end

require 'observer'

class Car
  include Observable

  attr_reader :mileage, :service

  def initialize(mileage = 0, service = 3000)
    @mileage, @service = mileage, service
    add_observer(Notifier.new)
  end

  def log(miles)
    @mileage += miles
    changed
    notify_observers(self, miles)
  end
end

car = Car.new(2800, 3000)
car.log(100)
car.log(100)
```

Here, method `notify_observers(self, miles)` will pass `*args` (here it is `self, miles`) to the *observer* (instance of `Notifier.new`) which created by `add_observer`.
Am I right about upper understanding?

I have two questions about upper code:

1. the class `Notifier` only have one method `update`, no `initialize`. So the `*args` (`self, miles`) will be passed to `update` directly?
2. whether the `self` in `self, miles` is static or dynamic? Is it `car` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. [Here's what it does](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveModel/Observing/ClassMethods.html#method-i-notify_observers):

   ```
   #File activemodel/lib/active_model/observing.rb, line 73
   def notify_observers(*arg)
     observer_instances.each { |observer| observer.update(*arg) }
   end
   ```
2. `self` will become a value when `notify_observers` is called. So in this case, it will be the `Car` instance you are calling `log` on (`car`).